# Copy the same values in the same table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, copy, multiple-columns

Let's say I have the following table named "products":

```
cod_pro | stock (multiple columns) | store
```

I want to copy the stock for some products(using cod pro and store) in the same table as an update, let's say for the product A I want to move the information I have from the product B(all of the information is in this table).

I do not know for sure how I should copy all of the information depending on the store and codpro.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be helpful

Comment: Your " stock(multiple collums) " is _highly_ suggestive of a seriously flawed design. It appears that your table is not properly designed to Third Normal Form.  As for your question itself - it is very unclear.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You question is rather hard to follow.  But if you want to duplicate all the rows for `'A'` and call them `'B'`, then use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into products (cod_pro, stock, store)
     select 'B', stock, store
     from products
     where cod_pro = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
insert into products (select * /*OR SELECT COLUMN*/ from table_name where column_name='xx')
```

Or this.

```
Declare
   cursor c_row_ is
   select * from products; 
Begin
    for r_row_ in c_row_
     loop
       insert into products (column_1, column_2, column_3)
       values ('ABC',r_row_.column_2, r_row_.column3);
     end loop;
End;
```